# Changing the language for Subversion error messages

Tags: svn, internationalization

For some reason, subversion is returning me error messages in what I think is German:

```
# svn up . 
svn: Zielpfad existiert nicht
```

Unfortunately, I don't know that language...  Before I resort to using a online translation engine to work with this, I figured I'd try to fix it.  I figure I'm just doing something very simple wrong.  I'm running subversion 1.6.4 installed via yum on centos (upgraded from 1.4.something that was having the same problem).  This is on a VPS admined with CPanel.

From what I can tell, it's trying to load english messages and failing.  I see this in the strace output:

```
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/subversion.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/subversion.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(0x4106d000)                         = 0x4106d000
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Normal SVN commands are in english (svn help, svn help up, etc), just the error messages are in german.  For all I know, it's been this way the whole time I've used the machine and I've just never gotten an error message from Subversion...

```
:: locale
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES=en_US
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

I've also run:

```
export LC_MESSAGES=en_US
export LANG=en_US
```

Any ideas what I should be looking at next?

Update:
Based on Phil's suggestion, I've run

```
export LANG=C
export LC_MESSAGES=C
```

and now locale outputs:

```
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES=C
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

And it still is giving german messages...  I'm beginning to think the version of subversion I have was compiled with German messages, and since it's not finding any language-specific message files, I'm getting the built-in German messages.  Now to figure out how that happened....

Comment: Yep, that's German. "Destination path does not exist."

Comment: This is getting annoying -- I've run strings/grep on every file strace says was loaded looking for "Zielpfad", and I'm getting nothing...

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you rename the German locale directory / file? In my case, the first one it finds (according to strace) is /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/subversion.mo

Comment: According to strace, it's not trying to load german messages (when LANG=C, there's no attempts to load anything from /usr/share/locale).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting those locale variables to "C". That means that nothing should be passed through any translation engine.

```
export LANG=C
export LC_MESSAGES=C
```

that should be enough. If it's still throwing German at you, I think maybe I'd start questioning how you installed Subversion.

Comment: Perfect! Worked on windows too with `set` instead of `export`.

Answer (score 11):

If you are having this issue in Windows, it's likely that your system code page is set to a language other than english. In windows, the subversion.mo files are stored at:
"c:\Program Files\Subversion\share\locale"
possibly "c:\Program Files (x86)" if you're on a 64 bit system.
If you rename the language it's displaying it now, subversion should default back to english.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem. We put on the .bashrc

```
export LANG=en_US
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me while add `export LC_MESSAGES=C` to ~/.bash_profile file based on this article http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.l10n.html

`export LANG=C` break international characters displaying in file name on my side.