# SVN command line client outputting garbled Unicode instead of English

Tags: svn

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtnpg.png

Here is a screenshot of it.

I am running svn on Windows 7, maybe that makes a difference?

When I run locale:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion>locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How do I set LANG back to en_US? Any ideas?

I've also tried the link that Pekka suggested, the export function doesn't work(?) for me.

NOTE: On windows command line it is displaying the unicode, when i tried svn on Cygwin, it works fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you link to where you downloaded the binary from? What is your default system language?

Comment: @Pekka default language should be english. I've no clue where or when I installed this svn, I've using git for so long. But I'm guessing it is from http://subversion.tigris.org/

Comment: Are you sure about the English setting? This SO question suggests that svn is somehow locale aware: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315749/changing-the-language-for-subversion-error-messages

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion>locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

my locale, I tried to use that export, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Pekka I dont think this is gonna be easily resolved, but can you please post a link(as answer) to a good/working svn in english. Thank you!

Comment: the thing is, the tigris.org downloads should be ok. I don't know whether they are purely english though - they may have multi-locale support compiled in. THe only idea that comes to mind is to check Windows' country setting in the control panel, if you didn't do that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall from a proper source got rid of the problem...